# I would like to write a method to read from txtfile, this method works, but keep looping, cannot stop

Tags: java

I am new to java, this is the method to read from text file and save to string, because I want it to show in a javafx textArea(), it works, but it will keep reading all lines again and again, the loop can not stop. Can someone help please

```
    public static String getAllResults() throws IOException {
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
                              FileReader("gameResults.txt"));
        String line = "";
        // Read a single line from the file until there are no more lines to 
        //read
        String currCol=null;
        //first loop to read from textfile by line
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, ","); 
            currCol = new String(); // Each currCol has 5 fields
            //System.out.println(line);


            while (st.hasMoreTokens()) { 
                //second loop using hasmoretokens() operator to check and 
                //keep read if there is more token
                currCol+=line; //st.nextToken().toString()
                //System.out.println(currCol);
            }

            //resultList.add(currCol);
            //System.out.println(resultList);
        }
        br.close();
        return currCol;
    }
```

Comment: If you don't call st.nextToken()`, st.hasMoreTokens()` will always be true. Consider just using `line.split(",")` instead of the inner loop anyway.

Comment: I tried something like currCol=st.nextToken();  its not work @@ anyway I will keep trying

Comment: What are you actually trying to return from this method?

Comment: in text file there is many line, each line contain 3 files, I try to read this whole file into String, then return to a textArea

Comment: If you want the whole thing as a single `String`, you don't really need to split up the tokens at all, do you? Or is there some other reason you are doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the entire contents of the file as a single string, you can do:

```
public static String getAllResults() throws IOException {

    Path path = Paths.get("gameResults.txt");
    return Files.lines(path).collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

"StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead."

You can write your inner loop like this

```
    String[] result = line.split(",");
 for (int x=0; x<result.length; x++){ //write your stuff here}
```